# Why is the dds file environment map transparent?

Tags: three.js

I've used an example of the dds file in the three.js example and it seems to be happening even though it doesn't have the effect of making it transparent. Is it just an optical illusion?

I tried this dds file.
envMap ▽
https://threejs.org/examples/textures/compressed/Mountains.dds

map▽
https://threejs.org/examples/textures/compressed/disturb_dxt1_nomip.dds

var loader = new THREE.DDSLoader();

```
        var map1 = loader.load( 'imgs/disturb_dxt1_nomip.dds' );
        map1.minFilter = map1.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
        map1.anisotropy = 4;

        var cubemap1 = loader.load( 'imgs/Mountains.dds', function ( texture ) {
            texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
            texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
            texture.mapping = THREE.CubeReflectionMapping;
            sphere.material.needsUpdate = true;
        } );

        var geometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(5, 32, 32);
        geometry.computeVertexNormals();
        sphere = new THREE.Mesh(
            geometry, 
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                envMap: cubemap1
            })
        );

        scene.add(sphere);
```

I wonder why the results come out like this. Can someone explain it?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/efLPV.jpg

Comment: Do you see any warnings in the browser console?

Comment: BTW: It's not intended to execute `computeVertexNormals()` after you have created an instance of `SphereBufferGeometry`. The normals of the geometry are already fine.

Comment: @Mugen87 `three.js:15440 THREE.WebGLRenderer: WEBGL_compressed_texture_pvrtc extension not supported.` : this warning